# How to build sphinx documentation for django project

Tags: python, django, documentation, documentation-generation, python-sphinx

I have a django project, which I document using reST in docstrings to do the following:

1. Help diagloags within IDE
2. Later on to build HTML documentation using Sphinx

My documentation shows up properly within IDE (PyCharm), however I can't configure Sphinx to generate HTML documentation for me.

Here is the structure of my project

```
+--------------------------------------------+
|  /saassapp         # django project path   |
|     /docs          # dir for sphinx        |
|        conf.py     # sphinx config file    |
|        ...                                 |
|     settings.py    # django settings       |
|     /studyview     # django app            |
|        ...
|     ...                                    |
+--------------------------------------------+
```

Any ideas? An examle of the conf.py file would be very useful. Thank you.

**EDIT**

My project name is saassapp and the module I am trying to make a doc for is called studyview.

- Sphinx `conf.py` file: http://pastebin.com/HTYdc1rR
- Sphinx `index` file: http://pastebin.com/bu1r38TQ
- Result of `make html`: http://pastebin.com/MWJj94EE

Comment: Have you run the [spinx-quickstart](http://sphinx.pocoo.org/tutorial.html) script? It sets up the Sphinx environment for you.

Comment: yes. I just can't figure out a proper config for it. no matter what I try, when I run the `make html` command, I get errors regarding importing django settings...

Comment: You'll have to show us the errors that you get.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The migration features introduced in Django 1.7 prevents the previous answers from working on newer versions. Instead you will have to do a manual setup. Analogous to all previous answers you'll first have to make sure Django can find your settings, and then call `django.setup()` which will load the settings and setup your models. Add this to your Sphinx project's **conf.py**:

```
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'projectname.settings'
import django
django.setup()
```

Comment: This works well, except if the ``automodule`` directive contains eg. ``:undoc-members:``. In that case, Sphinx extracts the documentation from the parent classes and misses some of them (for instance ``models.FileField``). This works well if ``:undoc-members:`` is removed and the class attributes are properly documented.

Comment: I keep getting a `ImportError: No module named 'projectname'` when I try a `make html`. Do you know what it might be?

Comment: @JoabMendes: Unless you explicitly named your Django project `projectname` you have to adjust that to whatever you named your project module. In other words, `DJANGO_SETTING_MODULE` should hold a valid python path pointing to your project's settings module.

Comment: @Simon it holds the projectname, I just used it as example haha. I specified the  `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` but I'm using a separate settings architecture. Inside the main project folder I have a settings folder with `base`, `local ` and `production` settings files. Both, local and production import base. So my `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` is something like `projectname.settings.local`. Do you think I need a specific configuration in this case? (I have tried to edit the sys.path) Also, I cannot import any module directly in conf.py (My tree: http://pastebin.com/y0HqZ8pz)

Comment: @JoabMendes Oh sorry, I thought that was literally the error message you got. I think it should work as long as you specify a complete Django settings file, regardless of where it's located. But as you can't import any other modules either I would first look into python path and/or virtualenv setup to make sure you can import the settings module in a python REPL.

Comment: @Simon I made a work around importing every module I wanted to autodoc directly in conf.py with their full paths (In this way for python 3.4: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/67631/how-to-import-a-module-given-the-full-path?answertab=active#tab-top). The only problem, as I said,  is that I have to import manually all the modules. Well, thank you anyway for your attention. (:

Answer (score 14):

Add the following to your conf.py and you will not need to set DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE each time:

```
import sys, os

sys.path.append('/path/to/your/project') # The directory that contains settings.py

# Set up the Django settings/environment
from django.core.management import setup_environ
from myproject import settings

setup_environ(settings)
```

Comment: is it better to do the sys.path in absolute terms or in relative terms?

Comment: Using a relative path will make it more reusable.

Comment: Thanks, the sys.path.append line with an absolute path saved me a big headache.

Comment: With the mentioned directory structure, I cannot see how you could call the Django project like a module from the sphinx conf file.

Comment: `setup_environ` seems to be deprecated

Answer (score 12):

With Django 1.6, I couldn't use the answer by @MikeRyan since `from django.core.management import setup_environ` has been deprecated.  Instead, I went to my **conf.py** file and added the following:

```
import sys
import os

sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..'))
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'dataentry.settings'
from django.conf import settings
```

Let me explain each line:

1. I used a relative path (two directories up), but you can go ahead and put an absolute path if you'd like
2. My project name is `dataentry` and the **settings.py** file is inside that folder; change the name (dataentry) to your project name

Comment: thanx for the update. Ill change to accept your answer to keep things up-to-date.

Answer (score 4):

I think you have to make Sphinx aware of the DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE environment variable. So do

```
export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=mysite.settings
```

(or whatever is the right value for you)

Then execute

```
make html
```

in the same terminal session.

Comment: You can use the subprocess module

Answer (score 0):

Late but using `Django>=1.9` and `sphinx>=1.6.4` set the path equivalent to the project `BASE_DIR` in the `conf.py`

```
import django
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))))
os.environ["DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE"] = "project.settings"
django.setup()
```

Answer (score 0):

You actually don't need a separate `settings` module. It's sometimes easier to have one (when tests and doc share settings) but not required.

This is [how dj-stripe sets up django for sphinx](https://github.com/dj-stripe/dj-stripe/blob/master/docs/conf.py). The key here is the `settings.configure` call with `INSTALLED_APPS` as it is the only one setting key required (if your app does not require more of course):

```
import django
from django.conf import settings
from django.utils.encoding import force_text
from django.utils.html import strip_tags

import djstripe  # noqa


# If extensions (or modules to document with autodoc) are in another directory,
# add these directories to sys.path here. If the directory is relative to the
# documentation root, use os.path.abspath to make it absolute, like shown here.
# sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('.'))
cwd = os.getcwd()
parent = os.path.dirname(cwd)
sys.path.append(parent)


settings.configure(
    INSTALLED_APPS=[
        "django.contrib.admin",
        "django.contrib.auth",
        "django.contrib.contenttypes",
        "django.contrib.sessions",
        "django.contrib.sites",
        "jsonfield",
        "djstripe",
    ],
    SITE_ID=1,
    STRIPE_PUBLIC_KEY=os.environ.get("STRIPE_PUBLIC_KEY", ""),
    STRIPE_SECRET_KEY=os.environ.get("STRIPE_SECRET_KEY", ""),
)


django.setup()
```