# How to document Django URLs with Sphinx?

Tags: django, python-sphinx

I'm generating a new Django project, with several apps. The main goal for this project is to create a REST API. Right now, I've Sphinx working, creating documentation of all my project with

```
sphinx-quickstart
```

and

```
sphinx-apidoc -o doc/packages .
```

All works well, except for URLs. I wanted to have my URLs documented, as a nice API, fully integrated with the rest of Sphinx documentation.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

It is. This isn't directly documenting the URLs, but I connected the URLs to view documentation in this way:

Make a Sphinx extension that looks something like:

```py
from django.core.urlresolvers import get_resolver

def setup(app):
    app.connect('autodoc-process-docstring', process_django_view)

def process_django_view(app, what, name, obj, options, lines):
   if what=='function':
       res = get_resolver()
       if res.reverse_dict.has_key(obj):
           url_struct = res.reverse_dict[obj]
           lines[:0] = [
               "| URL structure: %s\n" % url_struct[0][0][0]
               ]
```

Then you need to add it to extensions in your `conf.py` and also load in the Django environment like explained here: [How to build sphinx documentation for django project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7733577/how-to-build-sphinx-documentation-for-django-project)

There's some other stuff like the regex in `url_struct` and the parameters that you can include. My own also searches multiple URL resolvers that correspond to different domains.

Comment: `get_resolver()` requires one param: the url conf file. Add `from yourapp import urls` at the top of this file and then add the `urls` param to the call to `get_resolver`.